# mysql select 3 items from each group and output result set in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Product" like this:

```
store_id    product
----------------------------------
1           A
1           B
1           C
1           D
1           E
2           AA
2           BB
2           CC
2           DD
```

What's the mysql query to randomly select 3 products from each store, AND place the product on its own column for each store so I get a result set like:

```
store_id    product_1    product_2    product_3
------------------------------------------------
1           A            D            E
2           BB           CC           DD
```

???

Thanks,

Commonboy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the result you need:

```
SELECT
  store_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row=1 THEN product END) product_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row=2 THEN product END) product_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row=3 THEN product END) product_3
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN @last=store_id THEN @row:=@row+1 ELSE @row:=1 END row,
    store_id,
    product,
    @last := store_id
  FROM (
    SELECT store_id, product
    FROM products
    ORDER BY store_id, rand()
    ) s
) r
WHERE
  row<=3
GROUP BY
  store_id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f94/1).

On the s subquery I'm ordering all products by store_id and then by random, on the r subquery I'm calculating the row number, and on the outer query I'm pivoting the result (I'm grouping by store_id, and I'm putting row 1 into column product_1, row 2 into product_2 row 3 into product_3).